# js replacement with different name

Tags: javascript, replace

There is a replacement function deal with my JSON, because the original data has Chinese words, I need to change all Chinese words to English:

```
        function doReplace(repl, str) {
            var regexStr = Object.keys(repl).map(function(s) {
                return s.replace(/([^\w\s])/g, '\\$1');
            }).join('|');
            return str.replace(new RegExp(regexStr, 'g'), function(m) {
                return repl[m];//it changed to "repl"  
            });
        }

        var reData, newData, result;
        var returnArray = [];

        function candidateReFunc(dataArray,elected,lost){
                var txtData = JSON.stringify(dataArray);
                var replacements = {
                    "行政區": "district",
                    elected:"candidate_elected",
                    lost:"candidate_lost"
                }
                reData = doReplace(replacements, txtData);
                newData = JSON.parse(reData);
                returnArray.push(newData);
        }
```

`elected` and `lost` bring Chinese word into the `candidateReFunc()`:

```
candidateReFunc(array1,"候選人1","候選人2");
candidateReFunc(array2,"候選人3","候選人4");
```

**original JSON data**

行政區:"台北",
候選人1:"xxx" ...

**do candidateReFunc() JSON data**

district: "台北",
候選人1:"xxx" ...

but the result dose not as I expected, the word "候選人1" has not been bring `candidateReFunc()`.
What's wrong with it?

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52811784/edit) then click the `[<>]` snippet editor and create a [mcve]

Comment: The `elected` and `lost` variables on `candidateReFunc` seems to not be used at all, are you pasting the right code?

Comment: `elected` and `lost` as variables which used to be bring the string to `candidateReFunc` ...but maybe it dose not do like this?